# Purpose of array_udiff's positive/negative returned callback value and use on strings

Tags: php, arrays, callback, array-difference

I am interested whether property `aString` is different in these two arrays of objects:

Array 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [aString] => two
            [b] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [aString] => four
            [b] => 4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [aString] => six
            [b] => 6
        )
)
```

Array 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [aString] => two
            [b] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [aString] => newfour
            [b] => 4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [aString] => six
            [b] => 6
        )
)
```

Per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php):

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

**How is greater or less than determined when dealing with strings?**

Before asking this question, I modified the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php) Example #1 which uses stdClass Objects from this:

```
function compare_by_area($a, $b) {
    ...    
    if ($areaA < $areaB) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($areaA > $areaB) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

to this (*notice how I switch the swapped the returned sign*):

```
function compare_by_area($a, $b) {
    ...    
    if ($areaA < $areaB) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($areaA > $areaB) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and it returned the exact same results.  **What is the effect of greater or less than in `array_udiff()`'s returned callback value?**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver  Ah, so a string's negative/positive delta value is determined by comparing its binary value (using pack?)?  Okay, I guess this makes sense.  But still why does `array_udiff()` care if it is greater or less than if it doesn't do anything with this information?

Comment: But, if you want to only see a _difference_ does it matter if it's greater or less than?

Comment: @AbraCadaver  I saw your earlier deleted comment, and realized I stated they were objects but I meant array of objects, and edited the post.

Comment: @AbraCadaver No it doesn't matter if it is greater or less than.  Will it ever matter?  It doesn't seem that it will, and if not, why not just request true/false if it is different?  But since the documents allow for positive and negative, I expect I am missing something.